# How can I increase IP address by given number in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ip, delphi-7

I want to do someting like that:

```
var
ip,ip2: string;
begin
ip:= '127.0.0.1';
ip2:= ip+1;
end;
```

after this code executed ip2 should be 127.0.0.2

Question is: How can I increase an IP address like that?

Comment: What should happen to `127.0.0.255`?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand 127.0.1.0? It's just an example. I need to know how to increase IP address. I gave 127.0.0.1 as an example.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't defined the meaning of the term 'increase an IP adreess' precisely. For example, it is not clear what `127.0.0.255` increased by `1` should be. (It CANNOT be `127.0.0.256`.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes I know it can't be 256. What's your point?

Comment: So you want it to be `127.56.23.95`, or `0.41.27.57`, or ...? (Seriously, though: do you want it to be `127.0.0.0` or `127.0.1.0`?)

Comment: You can convert an IP address to an integer and back again with functions like inet_aton() in C. I don't think such a thing exists in Delphi though.

Comment: (You mean `127.0.2.0`, right?) Good, I thought so, but it wasn't obvious.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I think it should be 127.0.1.0 not 127.0.2.0 Am I wrong?

Comment: Leadri: You write "after 127.0.1.255 it should be 127.1.0.0". You certainly meant `127.0.2.0` :)

Comment: Ah you're right sorry! I just confused :) Yes I mean it should be 127.0.2.0

Comment: @PherricOxide  you are welcome! MAKEIPADDRESS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761385 while Delphi documentation fails to mention it, it is defined in stock `unit Winapi.CommCtrl;`

Comment: I created an [IP library](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX/blob/main/IP.pas) to do proper IP math given string representations of IP addresses for both IPv4 and IPv6. It includes an address Offset property that is read/write that can be used to increment or decrement an IP address, and it will let you know if you have gone beyond the limits of the network.. As a demonstration of the library, I wrote an [IP calculator](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might try the following:

```
type
  TIPAddress = array[0..3] of Byte;

function IncIPAddress(const IPAddress: TIPAddress;
  Value: Integer = 1): TIPAddress;
begin
  PInteger(@Result)^ := PInteger(@IPAddress)^ + Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  IPAddress: TIPAddress;
  IPAddress2: TIPAddress;
begin
  IPAddress[3] := 127;
  IPAddress[2] := 0;
  IPAddress[1] := 0;
  IPAddress[0] := 1;

  S := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [IPAddress[3], IPAddress[2],
    IPAddress[1], IPAddress[0]]);
  ShowMessage(S);

  IPAddress2 := IncIPAddress(IPAddress);

  S := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [IPAddress2[3], IPAddress2[2],
    IPAddress2[1], IPAddress2[0]]);
  ShowMessage(S);
end;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks so much!

Comment: unit Winapi.CommCtrl; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761385 and friends

Comment: it is part of aforementioned `unit Winapi.CommCtrl` and Delphi documentation sucks again, but you should already get used to this.

Comment: TLama, could you explain your code for the rest of us? Why is it using pointers even for the result value? And what happens if the IP address is already 255.255.255.255?

Comment: @Arioch'The It's not just the documentation that sucks. There should be an IP address type in the standard library already. Even PostgreSQL has an IP address type!

Comment: @alcalde, it's the way [`how to typecast array of bytes to integer and back`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13634765/960757). I typecasted the input array of bytes to integer, incremented it and assigned this value throught the typecast back to the array of bytes to the `Result` variable. To your second question, `0.0.0.0` because the maximal byte values simply overflow to 0.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very natural way to store an IP address.

Comment: @alcade yes, but it should be IPv6 address. IPv4 is outdated and should be banned to use in modern programs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why ? well, i'd make this variant record instead, still - why ?  TLama - really, remake your code into variant record ;-)

Comment: @Arioch Because it won't be composable with apis that operate with IP addresses and use 32 bit integers to store IP addresses

Comment: @Arioch, if I had used a variant record, I wouldn't need to bother with such strange conversion at all. For IP address manipulation I'm personally using slightly modified [`IPTypes.pas`](https://svn.apada.nl/svn/NLDelphi-opensource/ngln/IPTypes.pas) unit by NGLN.

Comment: @Arioch IPv6 is not yet universal. Nowhere near in fact. So your suggestion is not practical.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Win2000 is long obsolete now, so IPv6 support is ubiquitous today. IPv6 SHOULD be universal and as such it needs out-of-the-box support in RTLs and other frameworks. Conversely IPv4 is obsolete 1st and is already supported in all practical languages with one or another well-known libs. It just does not need to change, it is already easily used everywhere whete it could have the minimal sense. What is suppressed by RTL's and frameworks badly catching up is IPv6 and thus only for it there is sense in making it 1st class citizen. IPv4 use should be discouraged,way too easy to use.

Comment: @Arioch It's a network protocol. Needs to be supported end to end. Congratulations for you that your machine supports v6. Enjoy communicating with yourself.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling Really, David, i don't need to communicate with Win98 and Win2000 machines. Sorry for you if you do.

Comment: @Arioch, well, probably I'm from medieval, but from about 11 years I'm programming I've never (yes, really, never) needed support of IPv6 and I was working on quite big projects. Maybe you might even use(d) some of them :-)

Comment: @TLama maybe. And what would i say - they are of those big stones that are holding as back, aren't they ? Roman roads were great for Europe once, but today you would not want them instead of highways. IPv4 leads to a lot of workarounds and workarounds tend to have compatibility problems. Yes, IPv6 system has be compatible with another IPv6 peer - but that is what the standard requires of them. However 2 NAT pinching ad hoc impl-s would almost inevitably be incompatible. Anything that mandates IPv4 as a primary protocol inevitably is holding us back. Just like saving configs in Program Files

Answer (score 13):

Using the api, as an alternative:

```
uses
  winsock;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  addr: in_addr;
begin
  addr.S_addr := htonl(ntohl(inet_addr('127.0.0.1')) + 1);
  ShowMessage(inet_ntoa(addr));
end;
```