# Pascal. Converting int to array of byte

Tags: arrays, byte, pascal

I have an integer with length 8, an example could be 12345678.
I need to turn this into an array of bytes such as xx yy zz gg

how do i go about converting this in pascal?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634240/delphi-xe3-integer-to-array-of-bytes

Answer (score 0):

In modern pascal, you can just cast the value, using parentheses.

For example, in free pascal:

```
{$mode fpc}
program bytecast;
uses sysutils;
  type bytes = array[0..3] of byte;
  var x : uint32 = $12345678; i : byte; b : bytes;
begin
  b := bytes(x);
  for i := 0 to 3 do Writeln('$',IntToHex(b[i],1))
end.
```

output:

```
$78
$56
$34
$12
```

Note that the "backwards" order here comes from the fact that I'm running on an x86 architecture, which uses a little-endian byte order.

If cross-platform portability is a concern, then you can either extract the bytes manually:

```
{ var r : uint32; ... }
for i := 0 to 3 do                                                          
  begin
    DivMod(x, $100, x, r); { needs 'uses math'. note: this destroys x! }
    b[3-i] := r
  end;
```

Now the bytes will be arranged in a more intuitive order, and the output of the earlier `WriteLn` loop becomes:

```
$12
$34
$56
$78
```

This will work on all platforms as well as any pascal dialect that prevents simple casting, at the cost of doing a little more work. (For another option, see the  [SwapEndian](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/swapendian.html) procedure and this FPC wiki page about [cross platform code](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Writing_portable_code_regarding_the_processor_architecture#Endianness).)